# how to fetch data from live servers and insert it into other server

Tags: php

I have two **servers**. The question is i want to select the information form one server's table and insert it into other server's table. for that how many files i need.

I am able to select table data form server one but i don't know how to insert it into server two's table.

can any one help me or give me brief idea which will work

$sql="SELECT * FROM import_address_book LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die();

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id = $row[id];
$mobile_no = $row[mobile_no];
$user_id = $row[user_id];
$userEmail = $row[userEmail];
$name = $row[name];
$email = $row[email];
$type = $row[type];
$country = $row[country];
$gpwd = $row[gpwd];
$status = $row[status];
$dateCreated = $row[dateCreated];
$gender = $row[gender];
$city = $row[city];
$income = $row[income];
$profession = $row[profession];
$experience = $row[experience];
$pincode = $row[pincode];
$blacklist = $row[blacklist];

}
```

how to insert it in other server

Answer (score 0):

Call mysql_connect() on each server, so that you have two open connections. Then do a *select* query on one and an *insert* statement on the other.

If this is a one-time conversion, you may be better off by installing phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench and using that to do an export and import.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of the table is on the other server then use `mysql_connect()` to both servers use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to determine if a column exist and then build your insert statement base on the exist columns. This way, you can avoid exception when a specific column has been removed.

Comment: i know column names of both tables. where to write insert query for insertion. in while loop or in separate page

Comment: even though you know the columns are there, i will still advice you using `information_schema` to check if column exist to avoid future errors, for example when a specific column is been modified. Since your table might have multiple rows, it is advisable you build the  collection of insert statements within the while loop. And then fire the actual remote request for insert outside the while loop. Example:  `$insert_query = '';while(..){insert_query."statement";}'